# Trying to create a server component to send a json resultset from a local mysql db. How to get the server object (RowDataPacket) to the client?

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, typescript, next.js

The big picture: I've rendered server-side pages and even written forms using react hooks enabling database updates. I'm having a hell of a time integrating Ag-Grid - features that would be so nice to have in my app. I get the data out of the database (mysql2 module) and find it already rendered in json. Attempts to NextResponse.json() to deliver to the client side (aka, ag-grid) causes 'type' violations. Typescript is just so awkward to use (for the uninitiated) - but, I'm >almost< there.

So, I discovered that mysql delivers two packet objects with a result set - the first object is a RowDataPacket containing the result set data in a preformatted json. The second packet is the FieldPacket containing the column DDL of the result set (which is disposable for this exercise).

I'm thinking, ok then, serve the json up on an api endpoint to the client-side and make use of the react hooks useState, useEffect, et al to populate an ag-grid client-side. It *should* be this ez but it's not. I've made it this far without Express, Axios, Prisma, Vercel and the like - just Next.js - I feel I'm pretty close but need a little more detail to pull me over the top.

I guess one approach would be to read the json recieved, re-render it into a usable (transmissable) state, and the serve the *new* json at the api. This seems to require an egregious amount of effort and excessive manhandling/mangling that will almost certainly load the server up - can't possibly be the vision of the design. I've seen a lot of other discussions (albeit, older) on this topic - no real answers (yet).

Any help I can get will be greatly appreciated.

[The Big Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn4rf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG. So ez! The issue had *nothing* to do with converting JSON data from mySQL, nothing to do with Typescript, and *>everthing<* to do with NextJS automatic routing. I've been working on the front end for so long that I didn't realize that automatic HTTP routes use a 'router.ts/js[x]' page and not a 'page.ts/js[x]' page.

NextJS 14 is absolutely brilliant!

Project structure is everything:
[the server routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTCjQ.png)

and the *FULL* route.tsx code:

```
import { pool } from "@/config/db.config";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET() {
  let query: string = "SELECT * FROM product";

  try {
    const connection = await pool.getConnection();
    const [ rows, fields ] = await connection.query(query);

    connection.release();

    return NextResponse.json(rows);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed query: ", error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

One more gotcha: the route handler must be a valid HTTP Request type - in this case GET().

That is all.